# How to make the direction of UI in JQueryMobile Apps from right to left

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, right-to-left

how to display UIs components direction from right to left, do I need to change the `css` code manually, or is there an easier way to do that from the library itself ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now, you indeed have to modify the CSS rules yourself.

See [these](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-mobile-rtl) [posts](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/rtl-right-to-left-languages-with-jquery-mobile-how-to) on the jQuery Mobile forum for details.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change both CSS AND JavaScript (To make sliders and flip switches work), however, I made these changes for both current jQuery Mobile versions and uploaded for anyone to use: http://www.intlaqa.com/jquery-mobile-rtl